# Possible mistake in geometry book

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCDS$ be a regular pyramid ($AB=BC=CD=AD$ and $SA=SB=SC=SD$). $E$ is the midpoint of $CD$ and $O$ is the centre of the base.
> Let $d$ be the distance between $AC$ and $SE$, and $h$ be the distance of $O$ from $SD$.

Show that $d\gt \frac{h}{2}$

I came across this problem in a textbook. In that textbook this problem is a little bit different, the line segments have lengths and there is a numerical answer. In the answers the lengths of $d$ and $\frac{h}{2}$ are the same.
I checked them with a 3d constructor and found that $d\gt \frac{h}{2}$. Can you help me find which of us is right?

A hint would be much more appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: How do you define the distance between two segments of line in three dimensions...?

Comment: What should the points $L,M,N$ mean here? It would be better to draw the points $O$ and $E$.

Comment: It is for another problem. Sorry, I didn't have time to fix it.

Comment: @DonAntonio   Isn't it the line segment which is perpendicular to both lines?

Comment: @TigranHarutyunyan I would have said the least length of a segment having one endpoint on one segment and one endpoint on the other. Which may or may not be perpendicular to any of them. The one you mention should be the distance between the lines the segments lie on.

Comment: @TigranHarutyunyan No, I don't think so...as this would imply both segments are parallel, which they need not be. Perhaps it is what Gae says: the infimum ( or minimum, if it is attained) of the distances of all points from one of the segment to all points of the other segment. This looks messy...

Comment: The (shortest) distance between a pair of skew lines can be found by obtaining the length of the line segment that meets perpendicularly with both lines.

Comment: This is the definition by Brilliant.                             https://brilliant.org/wiki/3d-coordinate-geometry-skew-lines/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from line $AC$ to line $SE$ is the same as the distance between line $AC$ and the plane parallel to $AC$ and passing through $SE$. That plane is easy to construct: if $M$ is the midpoint of $AD$, line $ME$ is parallel to $AC$ and $SEM$ is then the requested plane.

To compute the distance $d$ between $AC$ and plane $SEM$ we can conveniently choose point $O$ on $AC$ and observe that the altitude $OG$ of triangle $OFS$ is perpendicular to the plane, where $F$ is the midpoint of $EM$. Hence:
$$
d=OG={OF\cdot OS\over FS}=
{OF\cdot OS\over \sqrt{OF^2+OS^2}}.
$$
On the other hand, the distance $h$ of $O$ from line $SD$ is the altitude of triangle $OSD$, hence:
$$
h={OD\cdot OS\over DS}=
{2OF\cdot OS\over \sqrt{4OF^2+OS^2}}
$$
and:
$$
{d\over h}={1\over2}{\sqrt{4OF^2+OS^2}\over\sqrt{OF^2+OS^2}}=
\sqrt{1+2r^2\over1+8r^2}>{1\over2},
\quad\text{where}\quad r={OS\over CD}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually before I saw your post I had already solved it, but thank you so much for your answer. I highly appreciate it.